# gVim in Ubuntu is slow when switching tabs or navigating lines

Tags: vim, ubuntu, performance

It's been like this forever really. Because I worked both on Ubuntu and Mac OS X interchangeably I didn't care as much. Now I think maybe it's time to finally find out what is wrong with it.

THE PROBLEM: When I switch tabs or navigate the lines with arrows or <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd> keys and when I do it repeatedly (as if when trying to find the right tab holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>) it seems to be delaying the action. When I stop hitting the keys gVim may still be finishing the operations (for instance, I stop hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, gVim may switch 5 more tabs - the number depends on how long I've been hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - before it stops).

MacVim with similar settings in `.vimrc` works just fine. The delays are present both when Compiz is turned off and turned on. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this effect reproduced when you run gVim without plugins (`gvim -u NONE -U NONE`)?

Comment: Have you tried switching off syntax highlighting (`:syntax off`)? It may be that Vim is trying to sync the highlighting over a large range of lines.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar sluggishness when working with large files. I've found that folded blocks makes it worse, so try and open all folds - <kbd>zR</kbd>.

Comment: I don't use folding, it's unfolded by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [know bug in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/856779). Until it is patched in the official repositories, you can use this [PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~chihchun/+archive/experimental), which contains a fixed version of Vim. I just tried it and it fixes the issue.